# CUBESET Exists but CUBEVALUE returns #N/A

Tags: excel, mdx, cube

I have the following CUBESET Formula:

=CUBESET("ICV_Cube","[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00]")

Wrapping it in a CUBESETCOUNT returns 7 as expected.  So the tuple exists. Whoever, if I use the set in a CUBEVALUE Function as follows:

=CUBEVALUE("ICV_Cube","[Measures].[Volume]",CUBESET("ICV_Cube","[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00]"))

It returns #N/A.

If I pull the Measure value of each day individually, values are returned.  It is not a calculated measure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried this and worked without any issue. Only thing i see different in the formulas you supplied, you should be using ';' instead of ',' as an argument separator.=/

Comment: Office support documentation specifies to use comma delimitation.

Answer (score 0):

In here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CUBEVALUE-function-8733DA24-26D1-4E34-9B3A-84A8F00DCBE0

The definition is as follows:

```
CUBEVALUE(connection, [member_expression1], [member_expression2], …)
```

You are providing a set_expression hence the error.

You'll need to aggregate the set before passing it in. Maybe the following:

```
"AGGREGATE([Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00])"
```

or

```
"SUM([Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00])"
```

---

Another possibility might be to have the following in say cell B3:

```
=CUBEMEMBER("ICV_Cube","SUM([Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00])"))
```

Then the following for the value:

```
=CUBEVALUE("ICV_Cube","[Measures].[Volume]",B3)
```

Comment: The article you referenced sites that a member expression or a tuple can be used.  The embedded CUBESET should work.

Comment: @Peter a Set is not a Member or a Tuple, and you've used a Set. A set will mean things are nondeterministic, whereas a member or tuple will signal a distinct portion of the cubes space. In mdx these are actually data types - set, tuple, member.

Comment: did you try either of my suggestions of using aggregate or sum - these functions return single areas within the cube.

Comment: I tried both SUM and AGGREGATE:

 =CUBEVALUE("ICV_Cube","[Measures].[CABLE CV]","AGGREGATE([Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-02T00:00:00]:[Date].[Dt].&[2016-05-08T00:00:00])")